# restrict access to to web Application

Tags: javascript, jsp, web-applications

I have a JSP webapp developed in Eclipse as a dynamic web project.

we use a third party web application that invokes my application, I need to validate that only the requests that come from that application are allowed to create a new session in my application.

I´m tring to do it with javascript and thinking , as a last resource, to use a Filter class to know the request origin and define the behaviour.

the problem is that the user requires that the operation is done on the client side, meaning I have to use javascript or similar, I have read about document.referrer on JS, but so far nothing is shown on the console.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you do in the client using JS for handling sessions wouldn't be secure as it can be easily modified by a malicious user. Also, using the referer or any other http header params would be insecure as they can also be easily spoofed.

If this third party application is directly calling your application I imagine that you have some degree of control over it. Can you access and modify its source code or are you just using configuration params?

Ideally the third party application would use an authentication token on each request that it makes to your application. And these authentication requests as well as all the session handling logic would always be handled on the server side.

Comment: You are rigth when you said that i can't have the control. I don't have any way to modify the third part source code, i decided to applied the Filter Class extend of Filter. and put the reference into the web.xml to get all the httpRequest and handle via code the follow behavior. Thanks, for you answer.